# Python pandas datetime plot xticks not in even gaps

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

When using Python 3.7, Jupytermatplotlib 3.0.1, pandas 0.23.4 (all updated)
The xticks of pandas date plot (datetime64 Series) is in strange gaps.
How can I make the gaps uniform?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=80) # 80 days
y = pd.np.random.random(80)
plt.plot(x, y ,'o')
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
```

[image]

Comment: The code you put works fine with me; no strange gaps. Check if you have some configuration that is causing this error.

Comment: I am doing that in clean kernel. Where can other config hide? Which versions do you use?

Comment: I don't know what makes you say that there are strange gaps. The labelling is 01-15-29 of each month. February only has 28 days, so maybe matplotlib should label the last day instead of 29, then. But otherwise perfectly regular.

Comment: If you formulate this a bit differently, like "I wouldn't have expected to see the 29th of each month labelled" you can bring this up on the matplotlib [issue tracker](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/).

Comment: it should be solved in version 3.1. https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/12925

Answer (score 1):

You can "force" the positions of the ticks with [WeekdayLocator](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.WeekdayLocator):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

x = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=80) # 80 days
y = np.random.random(80)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y ,'o')
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.WeekdayLocator(interval=1))
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked for me. By the way, do you see the same results on your computer?

Comment: I hope to get explanation for the issue.